# Android VPN подключение

Tags: java, android, vpn

Не могу создать VPN подключение. Есть адрес сервера через который нужно создать подключение. Нашёл такой код...

```
// in Activity
Intent intent = VpnService.prepare(PromptActivity.this);
startActivityForResult(intent, VPN_REQUEST_CODE);

// in onActivityResult
// requestCode == VPN_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK
VpnService.Builder vpnBuilder = new VpnService.Builder();
vpnBuilder.addAddress(options.address, options.maskBits);
vpnBuilder.addRoute("0.0.0.0", 0);
```

Ошибка на строке.

```
 VpnService.Builder vpnBuilder = new VpnService.Builder();
```

**"is not an encoding class"**

Как можно организовать сервис что бы можно было переподключать соединение. Может мне нужно как-то получить в onActivityResult этот сервис? Очень мало иноформации по этой теме.

Comment: Какая ошибка-то?

Comment: @post_zeew "is not an encoding class"

Comment: Где Вы взяли класс `VpnService`?

Comment: @post_zeew import android.net.VpnService;
import android.net.VpnService.Builder;